# Can not Convert String Type' Error while Migrating from Swift 3 to Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, type-conversion, migration

So I created an app several years ago. I tried to migrate from Swift 3 to Swift 4 and when I compiled and ran it, I received this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'

```
public func htmlToAttributedString(text: String) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let htmlData = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let htmlString: NSAttributedString?
    do {
        htmlString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch _ {
        htmlString = nil
    }
    
    return htmlString
}
```

This script was created in a 3rd party library that I used in my project so I am unfamiliar with the commands as I was just using it for part of the app. I'm not sure what I should do to fix this. I've tried a couple of things but none so far have seemed to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Swift 4, the constants have been made into members of types. You now need:

```
htmlString = try NSAttributedString(
    data: htmlData!, 
    options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], 
    documentAttributes: nil
)
```

`documentType` is a member of [`NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/documentreadingoptionkey), and `html` is a member of [`NSAttributedString.DocumentType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/documenttype).